# Android ScrollView with RelativeLayout does not work

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have a problem with my Android project.

I created a view with a list of images and on a Nexus 5 screen I can see all these images, but on a smallest phone some of these images are overlapping.

So I decided to insert a ScrollView but I see lots of errors.

I found lots similar question but nothing works for me.

Can someone help me?

Without ScrollView this is the code that works fine:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="none" >

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff0088ff"
android:clickable="false">



<ImageView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/icona_pr"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/icona_pr"
    android:onClick="apriPreliminare"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/icona_p"
    android:contentDescription="@string/icona_p"
    android:onClick="apriPesantezza"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView" />

  [...]
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When in Android Studio I select the Design Tab to see a preview I see a longer screen. On a Nexus 5 It seems to works fine, nothing change, but on a Galaxy S2 The first 2 ImageView are overlapping.

Comment: I don't see a ScrollView in the code you posted. What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: I know, I tried lots of different code to insert a ScrollView and every code make lots of errors. So I want to know how to implement with my code.

Comment: The first step is to show what you tried (even if it didn't work). The second step is to tell us that the errors actually say, and where they are coming from. Is it an IDE error? Does it compile? Is it a runtime error that you see in the logcat?

Comment: I updated the code in the first post. I can compile

Comment: well since you're aligning the first imageview to the parent top left, you probably want to align each successive imageview to be below the one before it, that's probably where you're getting overlapping. so imageView2 should be layout_below="@+id/imageView", imageView3 should be layout_below="@+id/imageView2", and so forth. You may also find you don't need alignStart.

Comment: I tried you tip but Android Studio say: "Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Now there is another problem, I have set a background color but in screen such us Nexus 5 i see a with piece at the end of page. Because the scroll view fit the content. How can I set the background to fit the screen size of the phone as it was with the relativeLayout??

Comment: u just set the background of scrollview instead of relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView must contain your ONE target layout, if it is parent view of whole layout also add xmlns tag.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

       //Other staff in here

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I updated the code in the first post, I updated my code with the same code you posted but first 2 images are overlapping in a smallest screen

Comment: Sorry, but if you are trying to use RelativeLayout, you must set a relative connection beetween child views using tags "layout_below", "layout_above", "leftOf", "rightOf" etc. Read this refence:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Comment: Can you help my modify my code to insert the ScrollView?

Comment: Try to simply use LinearLayout instead of Relative. Set orientation to "vertical" and it will set your child views one below other in that way as they are in xml